# Clicking on specific div class using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<div class="slot " data-view="A" data-name="B" data-pos="0" data-price="275000" data-bot="11" data-id="5540150218" style="C)">
    <div class="name">B</div>
    <div class="price ball-1">275,000</div>
    <div class="bot">Bot 11</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use Javascript to select the data-id="5540150218" portion of this HTML code and click it. I'm new to coding and would appreciate any help.

Comment: You want to bind a click event to that?

Comment: Basically trying to click it like a button

Comment: Why dont you give the div an id and use Jquery $("#id").on('click',function(){});

Comment: @RajatBhadauria he doesn't want to bind an event to it. he wants to click it (trigger the click event)

Comment: ok then for that we can use $("#id").trigger('click'); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind it a click event:

```
$('body').on('click','[data-id="5540150218"]'function(){

     alert('clicked');
});
```

if you want to click it then:

```
$('[data-id="5540150218"]').click();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thank you very much!

Comment: Its not a good practice to bind the complete `body` content with a click event.

Comment: you are welcome. please mark as answer ;)

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani what if I want to select it by name (data-name) and there are several with the same name, how do I select all with the same data-name? When I try your code and replace the id with name it just doesn't work since there are several.

Comment: well `$('[data-name="name"]') ` will select all of them you `$('[data-name="name"]').click()` will click all of them. if you want to click only one of them (access only one) you can do: `$('[data-name="name"]').eq(0).click() `  which `eq(0)` means first element with that name as 0 is the index of first element.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani doesn't seem to work :( when I try to select them all, it clicks none of them :/

Comment: let me create a demo for you. just wait a minute

Comment: Alright, thanks a ton for the help

Comment: here is the demo, feel free to alter the code and check it: [https://jsfiddle.net/5u2hL9mh/](https://jsfiddle.net/5u2hL9mh/)

Comment: this one is more clear: [https://jsfiddle.net/5u2hL9mh/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/5u2hL9mh/1/)

Answer (score 1):

@noox perhaps you can use document.evaluate. So code might look something like this.

```
document.evaluate("//div[@data-id='5540150218']",document,null,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue.click()
```

Please do let me know if it worked.

Comment: This worked too :)

Comment: Didn't know that existed. Cool find!

Comment: @noox Glad that was helpful ! :)